# How to Use MAX (TO_DATE...) with 'RRRR-MM-DD'

Tags: plsql

I have program that is supposed to pull the latest Read Date at a location. The program is supposed to convert from the MM/DD/YYYY format to the 'RRRR-MM-DD' format. I wrote the query below

select LOCATION, MAX(to_date(READDATE, 'RRMMDD')) readdate
from mh
where LOCATION in ('0000000000023577', '0000000000067228')
group by LOCATION;

When I run the query above by itself, I get the correct result.
However, when I add to my entire program as a subquery, I get a "Literal does not match format string".

Comment: Date? Format? A date has no inherent format. You can display it as MM/DD/YYYY or DD.MM.YYYY or whatever other string representation you like. Just use `TO_CHAR` with the desired format (or even better have your app display the date according to the OS setting). It makes no sense to apply `TO_DATE` on a date.

Comment: You have tagged the request with `plsql`. PL/SQL is Oracle's programming language built into their DBMS. Do you want to tag `sql` and `oracle`?

Comment: What is READDATE column's datatype?